# How to track mobile Opens of email using Google Anayltics

Tags: html, css, email, google-analytics, cross-platform

To track the opens i have added the below code in my html

```
< img src='|link|' height='1px' width='1px'  />
```

and while sending replace the link with actual url

so when email lands to inbox image looks like this:

```
    < img src='http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X&cid=8970&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=8970&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=fashionat&cm1=1&cd1=8970' 
          height='1px' 
          width='1px' />
```

So my promblem is when i open email in mobile (android) , google anayltics  gives Windows(Operating system) for that campaign.
[ACQUISITION->  Campaigns ->  All Campaigns and filter to Techonlogy ]

And if i click the link in android directly not in email its gives anayltics Android (Operating system) for that campaign.

How to Resolved this issue?  so whenever email opens in mobile it will give me  result as android or ios opens.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you opened the mail, did you do so using the mWeb or using an app?

Comment: To view mail i used gmail mobile app.